# How to make a linux script understand "\ " as ' ' for pathing purposes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm currently building a linux shell script that needs to execute commands like: `mkdir /home/Área\ de\ Trabalho/test`
But it does not understand the "`\` " like bash does and only creates a directory named Área in my home folder. Is there any way to force the script to execute that command like bash does?

EDIT: An important detail I forgot is that the script receives the path via parameter from a c code. So the command would be `mkdir $4` for example where `$4` has the path above.

Comment: You are building a "Linux shell script" but it doesn't behave like Bash? There's no shell scripting language called "Linux". Better make it clear what shell you're using. But I've yet to come across a shell that doesn't understand backslash quoting.

Comment: Your edit was indeed a important detail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, you should use double quotes around your variables if they have spaces within and you want them to be a single argument to the command.

Furthermore you should enclose your variable within double quotes if you want them expanded, or single quotes if you want them not expanded.

```
a="foo bar"
mkdir $a               # Will create directories <foo> and <bar>
mkdir "$a"             # Will create directory <foo bar>
mkdir '$a'             # Will create directory <$a>
```